# How to prevent Keycloak from displaying the password in body?

Tags: angular, security, https, keycloak

I have an Angular app that is redirected to Keycloak login page. After the user login I check the requests that have been done, and there is one similar to:

```
https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/XXX/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=XXX&execution=XXX&client_id=XXX&tab_id=XXX
```

In this request I can see in the body the username and the password the user sent:

```
username=my_user
password=my_password
credentialId=""
```

This is not encrypted and I can see it easily on the browser. Of course this is unsafe, so I would like to know. How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to send password in your body.
You can test it on stackOverflow himself which send you login/password in clear and use SSL certificate.
You send your password one time and use token after that.
SSL certificate is a solution if you want to prevent MIM.

Comment: I understand. But what I mean is that I can see the password and the username explicitly in the browser. Is this not unsafe? I think all this information should be encrypted. Am I wrong? I will add this to my question btw

Comment: No it's not unsafe. Try disconnect and reconnect from this website (stackOverflow), inspect your brower when you reconnect and you can see your username and password  explicitly.

Comment: @JoséDanielMontoyaSalazar even if you can see the password and username in your browser, it doesn't mean that they are actually sent as plain text. As you can see from url, the request is sent over HTTPS protocol.  That means that whole HTTP communication with server is realized through encrypted SSL/TLS channel. You can see the password, because browser shows you your request before encryption.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand that! :)